# Receiving ID of draggable with Jquery and ondrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I added a code sniplet below. I have div-containers with id's that i can drag onto other div objects.

My goal is to add the ID of the draggables into the div-container it is added. 
It looks I have to add UI to the drop function but I do not know how to do this in the `ondrop` call. What would be the right solution?

```js
var overviewJS = new function() {
  this.allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
 $(ev.target).bind('dragover', function(){
       $(this).addClass('drag-over');
    });
    $(ev.target).bind('dragleave', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
    });
  }
  this.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  this.drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   $(ev.target).removeClass('drag-over');
   $(ev.target).effect("highlight", {color: '#b1b1b1'}, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.tbDocument {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #412418;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 120px;
}
.tbProject {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #412418;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
[draggable] {
  cursor: move;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  border: 2px dashed #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="1" class="tbDocument" draggable="true">
  document to drag
</div>
<div id="2" class="tbDocument" draggable="true">
  document to drag
</div>
<div id="3" class="tbDocument" draggable="true">
  document to drag
</div>
```

If I try `overviewJS.drop(event,ui)` in the ondrop method I receive an error that the UI is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was to add `ondragstart="overviewJS.drag(event)"` This method sets a variable that can later be received.

```
 <div id="3" class="tbDocument" ondragstart="overviewJS.drag(event)" draggable="true">
 document to drag
</div>
```